How to manage ISR in AWS Amplify with NextJs app router
I am writing NextJs frontend using NextJs 14 and ISR approach. All of my pages have revalidate set to 30 seconds. I use Amplify to deploy application. I caught very strange behaviour of cache on ISR pages.
Sometimes it gives me very old cache like 15 minutes ago.
Expected behavior: cache keeps maximum 30 seconds, then cache is revalidated. I see the newest data every 30 seconds (+ time for revalidation).
Current behavior: cache keeps for much longer time (15 minutes I saw). When I reload page I can randomly(by some reason) see old cache or new.
How to fix this behavior? Why old cache is kept so long on Amplify?

So when the 30 seconds has passed, and you access the page the server will tag the page as stale but still return the old cache. While it's returning the old cache, it will start to generate the new page ready for the next request. Maybe that's why it's taking longer than 30 seconds for you. To troubleshoot this behavior you can check logs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#debugging-cached-data-in-local-development

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
